# VLC Black Screen with NVIDIA driver

Tags: drivers, nvidia, display, vlc

After installing the NVIDIA-304 display driver, whenever I play a video with VLC and scale the window any higher than the native resolution of the video (or full screen), the VLC window goes black. Since my display has a resolution of 2560x1600, this occurs with all videos I watch. This problem DOES NOT occur when all other windows are closed. Sometimes, if I open another window after VLC and then close it, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove all the nvidia drivers you currently have installed:

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
```

Then install the correct, current drivers:

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current
```

Then reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Any explanation?